# How to find correlation in a data set

Tags: r

I wish to find the correlation of the trip duration and age from the below data set. I am applying the function `cor(age,df$tripduration)`.  However, it is giving me the output NA. Could you please let me know how do I work on the correlation? I found the "age" by the following syntax:

```
age <- (2017-as.numeric(df$birth.year))
```

and `tripduration(seconds)` as `df$tripduration`.

Below is the data. the number 1 in gender means male and 2 means female.

```
tripduration    birth year  gender
439              1980        1
186              1984        1
442              1969        1
170              1986        1
189              1990        1
494              1984        1
152              1972        1
537              1994        1
509              1994        1
157              1985        2
1080             1976        2
239              1976        2
344              1992        2
```

Comment: You must have done a typo somewhere, because when I run your sample code I get 8.37%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to subtract a number by a data frame, so it would not work. This worked for me:

```
birth <- df$birth.year
year <- 2017
age <- year - birth
cor(df$tripduration, age)
>[1] 0.08366848

# To check coefficient
cor(dat$tripduration, dat$birth.year)
>[1] -0.08366848
```

By the way, please format the question with an easily replicable data where people can just copy and paste to their R. This actually helps you in finding an answer.

---

Based on the OP's comment, here is a new suggestion. Try deleting the rows with NA before performing a correlation test.

```
df <- df[complete.cases(df), ]
age <- (2017-as.numeric(df$birth.year)) 
cor(age, df$tripduration)
>[1] 0.1726607
```

Comment: It is not working. I am unable to get the age with the above syntax. And hence, correlation also does not work. However, with the code that i sent -  age <- (2017-as.numeric(df$birth.year)), I was able to get the desired ages for the birth year. can we do something else ?

Comment: Try `cor(age, df$tripduration, dat, use="pairwise.complete.obs")`

Comment: Is your example a part of a large dataset that contains NA?

Comment: yes, I have just taken a part of the data here for reference purpose

Comment: does the dat in the cor(age, df$tripduration, dat, use="pairwise.complete.obs") mean the data set here ?

Comment: Yes, but if your larger dataset contains missing values, then my original suggestion may not work. I created a new suggestion. Please see the edited answer.